# Laravel 5.7 Servidor compartido: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, laravel, php7

Acabo de subir un proyecto a un servidor compartido. Cambié las rutas de `index.php` y otorgue permisos 777 a public y storage. Con esto se activo la vista de login en el dominio correctamente.
Configure la base de datos desde cpanel, cree un nuevo usuario y lo asigne a la base con todos los permisos.

Configure el archivo `.env` con los nuevos datos del servidor compartido.

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxxxxxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxxxxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
```

Al acceder al login con usuario y contraseña recibo el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'clicestr_cbroot'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = admin@gmail.com limit 1)

¿Alguien ya tuvo este inconveniente y lo pudo resolver? Me podrán brindar orientación de que otras alternativas puedo probar?

Gracias por destinar tiempo en mi consulta.

Comment: Hola, podrías fijarte en la tabla users y ver ese campo, si existe, si tiene dato, así interpreto el error que tienes

Comment: Creo que un simple `php artisan clear:cache` solucionaria ese error, o podria ser la ip: 127.0.0.1 quizas si lo cambias por localhost.

Comment: Si efectivamente era la ip. Muchas gracuas @Shassain

Answer (score -2):

Lo solucione cambiando en .env 127.0.0.1 por localhost.